# Pass Subject and Body parameter to a powershell Email script using batch file

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script ,

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'TLS12'
$Mail_to="Jill.maclaurin@ca.ibm.com"
$Mail_from="shuddha.roy@gmail.com"
$Subject = "Test"
$Body = "Test Body"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.sendgrid.com"

Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Port 587 -UseSsl -From $Mail_from -To $Mail_to -Subject $Subject -BodyAsHtml $body -Encoding ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
```

Now i want the `$subject` and `$Body` value to be obtained from a batch file and run the powershell script using that batch file, How to do it?

Comment: You need to add some parameters (e.g. `-Subject` and `-Body`) to your script, then call it like this:  `MyScript.ps1 -Subject "some text" -Body "more text"`.  More info here: [about_Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-6)

Comment: What do you mean, "subject and body obtained from a batch file"?  It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Add to the start of the script a `Param` Section, you can use default value for the required parameters, save the file.

```
Param(
$Subject = "Test",
$Body = "Test Body"
)

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'TLS12'
$Mail_to="Jill.maclaurin@ca.ibm.com"
$Mail_from="shuddha.roy@gmail.com"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.sendgrid.com"

Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Port 587 -UseSsl -From $Mail_from -To $Mail_to -Subject $Subject -BodyAsHtml $body -Encoding ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
```

Call the PS1 file from the batch file using the required paramters, e.g:

```
powershell script.ps1 MySubject MyBody
```

Comment: getting the below error "S:\prod\mhedqa\RWScripts>powershell S:\prod\mhedqa\RWScripts\EmailUpdate.ps1 "TEST1" "TEST1 Body" 
Send-MailMessage : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Subject'. The 
argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and 
then try the command again.
At S:\prod\mhedqa\RWScripts\EmailUpdate.ps1:17 char:99
+ ...  -UseSsl -From $Mail_from -To $Mail_to -Subject $EmailSubject -BodyAs ...
+                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
    "